# Automatic start of Tomcat on server restart (Linux)

Tags: tomcat

I have 4 Tomcat instances I wish to start when the server (Cent OS 2.6.9) restarts.

After all other services have started I would like to start these up - but I am a bit worried about the load of starting all 4 at the same time, so maybe a short delay would be necessary.

How should I go about this?

Comment: How are they being started up now? /etc/init.d/ ?  cron ?

Comment: Currently they require manual starting, ie I have to log in and run the startup script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have more than 15 tomcat instances in the same server and all started at once.

I have a startup script for everyone (i think you have it too, no?).

I create a startup_ALL_tomcat.sh script that execute all the startups (you can put a "sleep 60" command for delay) and create a link in /etc/rc3.d/S99tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

What are you worried will happen with the increased load?  If it's just that the servers will take a little longer to start up, then... I wouldn't worry about it.  That said, any details on how to make them start up a little later will depend on how they're being started up now.

Comment: Currently I start one at a time and wait for the CPU to reduce, after about a minute.